# POST .... 413 (Payload Too Large)

Tags: express, mern, body-parser, payload

this is my code from server.js

```
const express=require("express");
const mongoose=require("mongoose");
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors=require("cors")
const app=express();
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit:"50mb"}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: "50mb", extended: true, parameterLimit:50000}));
app.use(express.json());
```

I have tried every solution found on the internet but its still showing payload too large error.

Comment: `app.use(express.json());` would be *overwriting* the one above, dont use both

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I have removed it. Still getting same error!